# Adding another column from second table by matching ID

Tags: oracle

I have one table, which consists of ID, Value, Product, Name. I have another source table, where is Supplier and also the same ID number, as in previous table. What I want to do is to keep the first table as it is, so the columns are ID, Value, Product, Name and I want to add column Supplier from second table, based on matching the ID number from the first table.

My code looks like this:

```
select 
    a.ID,
    value,
    product,
    name,
    a.supplier
from 
    output_table
left join 
    main_table a on a.ID
where 
    a.period = 2022
order by 
    product
```

But this does not work for me at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of errors here.

First of all, the `join` has to be on a condition, not just the name of a field in one of the tables. Second, at least from your description, `a.supplier` doesn't make sense, because `supplier` is in the second table, not the first.

```sql
select a.ID,
value,
product,
name,
supplier
from output_table b
left join main_table a on a.ID = b.ID
where a.period = 2022
order by product
```

When you're naming a field/column, you only need to qualify it with a table name when the field name by itself is ambiguous--at least normally because both tables contain fields by the same name. In your case, that's necessary only for the `ID` field. Also `left` joins are the default, so you don't really need to specif that either. So, if I were writing it, I'd probably use something more like:

```sql
select a.ID, value, product, name, supplier
from output_table b
join main_table a on a.ID = b.ID
where period = 2022
order by product
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two different types of conditions you can use in `join condition` as follows:

- `ON`
- `USING`

So your join condition can be one of the following options:

**Option1(ON clause):**

```
from 
    output_table t
left join 
    main_table a ON a.ID = t.ID
where
```

**Option2(USING clause):**

```
from 
    output_table t
left join 
    main_table a USING ID
where
```

**Note**: While using `USING` clause, Do not use table alias before column name so wherever you use `ID`, just use `ID` and not `t.ID` or `a.ID`

Demo of `USING` clause:

```
with t1(ID, no) as (
    select 'AA',2111.03 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'BB',123.05 FROM DUAL
), t2(ID, start_range, end_range) as (
    select 'AA', 0, 100 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    ID, T1.NO, T2.START_RANGE, T2.END_RANGE
  FROM
         T1
      left JOIN T2 using (ID);


ID         NO START_RANGE  END_RANGE
-- ---------- ----------- ----------
AA    2111.03           0        100
BB     123.05
```